# htaccess rewrite for parameter, carrying forward a value

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hi I have tried to piece together a full working rewrite using pieces but not got very far.

I have thousands of pages e.g. /parts/?page=100 that I would like to forward to /parts/page/100/
but it gets complicated because the page parameter may not be first and I would also like all other parameter information to be stripped, so for example it should change the following

```
/parts/?page=100/            ->   /parts/page/100/
/parts/?xyz=1&page=100/      ->   /parts/page/100/
/parts/?xy=1&z=1&page=100/   ->   /parts/page/100/
/parts/?xy=1&page=100&z=1/   ->   /parts/page/100/
```

So far I have got this code to work but only for the top line from the list above.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^parts /parts/page/%1? [NC,R,L]
```

What rewrite rule would work for all the above examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)page=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^parts/?$ /parts/page/%1? [NC,R,L]
```

Use of `(?:^|&)` pattern will enable parameter `page` to be read at any position in Query string.